# Color area under pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to remove the actual line of the plot of a pandas timeseries and instead color the area under it (slightly transparent).

I found the [fill_between()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) module of matplotlib, but since it requires actual arrays as attributes, and I just call the `.plot()` function of the pandas series, I don't know how to apply this function.

This is a MWE, e.g., I would like to color the area under `ts_1`. How can I do that?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

idx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=5, freq='H')

ts_1 = pd.Series([0 , 0, 1, 1, 0], index=idx)
ts_2 = pd.Series([10, 6, 8, 1, 3], index=idx)

ts_1.plot(secondary_y=True, drawstyle="steps")
ts_2.plot()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that creates a matplotlib axis object first, then passes that to the pandas Series plotting function so that we can use the matplotlib `fill_between` method. Note: the key to getting this right for the step function is to set the keyword argument `step`='pre'. You can play around with the `alpha` to increase or decrease transparency.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))

idx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=5, freq='H')

ts_1 = pd.Series([0 , 0, 1, 1, 0], index=idx)
ts_2 = pd.Series([10, 6, 8, 1, 3], index=idx)

ts_1.plot(drawstyle="steps",ax=ax)
ax.fill_between(ts_1.index, ts_1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5,step='pre')

ts_2.plot(secondary_y=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

For easier control of axis labels etc., you could alternatively create a second axis object which shares the same x-axis as the first axis object, and then set the labels independently:

```
ax2 = ax.twinx()

ts_2.plot(ax=ax2, c='orange')

ax.set_ylabel('ts_1 y-values')
ax2.set_ylabel('ts_2 y-values')
```